# ArcGIS Pro Arcade If-And Statement

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade

I have an Expression that I am trying to create for symbology that essentially filters on three categories. The Two are very simple, the last one has a lot of criteria that work for it. For example, first two criteria are Parcels greater in size than 3 acres and the second is with building structures less than 6,005 SQFT. The last one is where I am having difficulty. I would like to sort the results from the above based on zoning types that work for a specific building type. Such that, only parcels with the first two criteria and proper zoning return True.

Here is what I have:

```
IF(
$feature['CountyParcel_DataCSV_2022.csv.ACREAGE'] > "3.0"
&&
$feature['CountyParcel_DataCSV_2022.csv.SQFEET'] < "6005"
&&
Includes ($feature['CountyParcel_DataCSV_2022.csv.Zoning'], 
"C1"||
"C2"||
"GC"||
"I" ||
"IC"||
))

{

return True;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the help file for [Includes()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/array_functions/#includes).  The first parameter is an array of values to test against, the second is the value to look for. I would imagine your code should be:

```
Includes(["C1","C2","GC","I","IC"], feature['CountyParcel_DataCSV_2022.csv.Zoning'])
```